# Ploting Phase Transition Diagram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, diagram, modeling, curve-fitting

I am trying to plot Phase Transition Diagram similar to the one shown below:

[image]

Right now, I am able to determine what the phase is for a given point `(T,P)` (whether it's water or ice or vapor). However, I am having trouble figuring out how to plot the boundary lines (such as the liquidus and solidus lines) like the ones in the figure.

I am not sure whether this is a proper question to ask here, but any input would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Basically you have to create a function, that given a T,P point returns and integer (phase index), this can be know from the free energy. The plot the index number as function of T,P in a http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/heatmap.html . Since Liquid-Vapor ends in a critical point... (welcome to the real world) you need to define an order parameter that changes discontinuously below the critical point and continuously above it. (for example based the compressibility if you have nothing else.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "Basically you have to create a function, that given a T,P point returns and integer (phase index), this can be know from the free energy. " <-- I have finished this step. "The plot the index number as function of T,P in a [heatmap]" <--- So my understanding is that by doing this, we "color" different phases with different color?

Comment: Yes, I don't know the details of Matlab but at the end you have to map (e.g. choose a color scale) that given number (that indicates the phase) it corresponds to a color.

Comment: I see thank you. I had this idea originally but don't know where to start. So, you suggest using heatmap for this purpose? an other question is that how can I explicitly plot (or fit) the boundary lines after I managed to differentiate phases with colors? Thank you so much.

Comment: Finding boundaries is much harder than coloring regions, they look like similar problems but they are not. The second is simpler and you have to do that anyway after finding the lines. I have been working in this problem for years and I didn't find a perfect solution. The best I could do is coloring plus discontinuity detection (to draw the lines)

Comment: Thank you so much. I truly appreciate your response. I am new to this kind of modeling so I have a dumb question. Taking this figure I posted for example (as well as many other Phase Transition Diagram available online), how did they managed to get the phase boundaries? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I think this types of plots are drawn by hand (which is cheating in my opinion). You can realize by looking the plots in details, if it is a vector image (PDF) you can always zoom in a bit a notice defects in the lines joints. In other cases, like your example, it is obvious the lines are 2D splines. For example there is a strange wiggle above the "t" in "water vapor" and the vapor-ice line looks and ends strangely near 0,0.

Comment: If you will succeed to generate membership functions, they are supposed to be a kind of step functions. Since your diagram is q 2D one you might find derivative in one of dimensions. Extrema of those point positions of boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain your approach in a bit more detail? Does this process involve very hard computational work? Thanks.